# Change input size of vggface pretained model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, vgg-net

It been a week that Im trying to change the input size of the pertrained  Vgg face model every time I change something it got me an error how can I change the input size from 224x224x3 to 64x64x3 is there a way to change it directly without training again the model just using the pertrained weights directly

```
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1),include_top=False,input_shape=(64, 64, 3)))

model.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

model.add(Convolution2D(4096, (7, 7), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Convolution2D(4096, (1, 1), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Convolution2D(2622, (1, 1)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Activation('softmax'))


from keras.models import model_from_json

deep= model.load_weights('/Users/macbookpro/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/vgg_face_weights.h5')
```

code: 
[vggface](https://sefiks.com/2018/08/06/deep-face-recognition-with-keras/)

When I try to call include_top i got this error:

```
TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'include_top')
```

When I change directly the input size i got this error:

```
ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 7 from 2 for 'conv2d_14/convolution' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,2,2,512], [7,7,512,4096].
```

Comment: Strange!! `64x64` is actually possible for this architecture. What error are you getting?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think the ZeroPadding2D layer doesn't have `include_top` parameter. Please include the full code and the error you get.

Comment: thanks for your comments guys I posted the link of the code its similar to my code

Comment: @marcoromelli that's true when I try to call include_top I got an error

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remove the `include_top=False`.
Your problem is that this architecture is too deep for a 64x64 input. In particular, this line:

```
model.add(Convolution2D(4096, (7, 7), activation='relu'))
```

is trying to perform a 7x7 convolution on an input of size 2x2 which is impossible.
A possible solution is to remove the Convolutions after the last MaxPooling layer and use some Dense layer instead.